# CMake: Compiler could not be found on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015, cmake

When I run this : `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"`

I have this output :

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/ce/type/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/ce/type/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

This is my CMakeLists (I have deleted the useless stuff for the exemple)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project(type)

option(BUILD_CLIENT "Build Client" ON)
option(BUILD_SERVER "Build Server" ON)

set(CLIENT_NAME "type_client")
set(SERVER_NAME "type_server")

set(CLIENT_SRCDIR "client/src/")
set(SERVER_SRCDIR "server/src/")

set(INC_DIR_CLIENT "client/includes")
set(INC_DIR_SERVER "server/includes")
set(INC_DIR_DLLOADER "DLLoader/")
set(INC_DIR_ECS "ecs/")
set(INC_DIR_PROTOCOL "protocol/")

set(LIB_LINKS "-ldl -lpthread")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

set(CLIENT_SOURCE_FILES
        ${CLIENT_SRCDIR}main.cpp)

set(SERVER_SOURCE_FILES
        ${SERVER_SRCDIR}main.cpp)

set(SERVER_SOURCE_FILES_SYSTEMS)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
if(WIN32)
    set(SFML_ROOT "dependancies/windows/SFML-2.4.1")
elseif(UNIX)
    set(SFML_ROOT "dependancies/linux/SFML-2.4.1")
endif()
find_package(SFML 2 REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)

install(TARGETS ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} DESTINATION bin)

if(WIN32)
    include_directories(${INC_DIR_DLLOADER}/win)
elseif(UNIX)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra")
    include_directories(${INC_DIR_DLLOADER}/linux)

    set(SFML_ROOT "dependancies/SFML-2.4.1")
endif()

include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})

if(BUILD_CLIENT)
  add_executable(${CLIENT_NAME} ${CLIENT_SOURCE_FILES})
  target_link_libraries(${CLIENT_NAME} ${SFML_LIBRARIES} ${LIB_LINKS})
endif()

if(BUILD_SERVER)
    if(WIN32)
        add_executable(${SERVER_NAME} ${SERVER_SOURCE_FILES}
                ${SERVER_SOURCE_FILES_SYSTEMS} ${SERVER_SOURCE_FILES_WIN})
        target_link_libraries(${SERVER_NAME} -lws2_32)

    elseif(UNIX)
        add_executable(${SERVER_NAME} ${SERVER_SOURCE_FILES}
                ${SERVER_SOURCE_FILES_SYSTEMS} ${SERVER_SOURCE_FILES_LINUX})
        target_link_libraries(${SERVER_NAME} ${LIB_LINKS})
    endif()
endif()
```

I installed the C++ compiler with Visual Studio, so I don't understand why the compiler is not detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to compile with `cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015"`